# What MySQL Collation should I use for Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2, database-schema

Looked for a Magento 2 version of this question but only found a Magento 1.
There's 4 that come to mind:

utf8mb4_general_ci

utf8_general_ci

utf8mb4_unicode_ci

utf8_unicode_ci

Which one should I choose for Magento 2.2 and upwards?

Comment: I used `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Why @KhoaTruongDinh what made you choose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

- utf8_unicode_ci
- utf8_general_ci

To learn more about the difference I think you should have a read over this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci

But it would be personal preference on which you will think will give you the best results based on your requirements.